# Is there a Hindi (Devanagiri) Font style that matches - Impact, Oswald and Anton - (Latin) fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation, font-design

I tried searching for a Hindi (Devanagiri) Font that matches the consdensed bold style of famous Latin font - 'Impact'.

[image: font : League Gothic]

Please let me know if there is a bold condensed font  like the above for Devanagiri Script to write in Hindi language. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with Google fonts, I've 2 suggestions:

1. [Teko](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Teko) Semi Bold looks like quite a match to your requirements.

[image]

2. *Similar* but less condensed font which I like is [Khand](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Khand) Bold:

[image]

Comment: Khand bold works better for the fact that it is a condensed font.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'Teko' looks very similar to what you are expecting and you can download it from google fonts. You can transform the type to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try November (and rounded version October) from Typotheque. It has condensed and Compressed styles which get very narrow and very bold. October is bundled for free on Macs.